# Animation of Activity in Activity

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I am designer, not a programmer so I will make it clear using graphics.
I have 2 activities that I want to have as one. When user clicks on each button, a new activity is being active (normally a new window would open). I want to have all the information (text, images) on one screen that will scroll down, like in this animation.

before click

[image]

after click

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html). It's exactly what you want. A scrollable list that has items that can be expanded.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a `LinearLayout` that looks like

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView/> <!-- Title, e.g. "Heating Program" -->
    <TextView/> <!-- Details, e.g. "Standby mode" -->
    <TextView/> <!-- Title -->
    <TextView/> <!-- Details -->
    <!-- etc -->
</LinearLayout>
```

If you set `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` for the LinearLayout and then set `detailsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` or `detailsView.setVisibility(View.GONE)` from `OnClickListener` (each title hiding/showing its detail) you will get about that effect. But it's not perfect.

Note: Requires Honeycomb or above. Animation can be customized via [setLayoutTransition(LayoutTransition transition)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#setLayoutTransition%28android.animation.LayoutTransition%29)

Answer (score 0):

I would make a custom `Layout` class that has all the `Views` in it (the main "Heating Program" view, arrow ImageView, and the details view), and give that class the knowledge of being "expanded" or not.  Then when the main view/arrow view are clicked, toggle the expanded-ness, change the arrow image, and set the visibility of the details view (like @zapl says).